# How can I get a partial match function in google apps script perform faster?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

To automate a repetitive task, I'm trying to write a function that will perform a partial match vlookup on some data. I wrote a function that loops through all the data that needs to be classified, looks for a match in the lookup table and outputs the classified data in a google sheet. The function works but its slow.

I tried it against a moderate sized data set of 20,000 rows and the function timed out after classifying some 800 rows only. This is the function:

```
/**
* Applies a partial vlookup on the data 
*
* @param {vlookupName}        : The name of the partial lookup sheet
* @param {sheetName}          : The name of the sheet find data
* @param {lookupName}         : The name of the lookup column
* @param {classificationName} : The name of the classification column
*
* @return Classifies data in the classification column
*/
function classifyData(vlookupName, sheetName, lookupName, classificationName) {
  
  // Get the data table & the lookup table
  var lookupSheet = ss.getSheetByName(vlookupName)
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  
  // Clear data in classification column
  var numRows = dataSheet.getLastRow()
  var classificationIndex = getColumnIndex(sheetName, classificationName)
  dataSheet.getRange(2, classificationIndex, numRows, 1).clear()
  
  // Get the partial match values from the vlookup table
  var maxPartialMatchRows = lookupSheet.getLastRow()
  var partialMatch = lookupSheet.getRange(1, 1, maxPartialMatchRows, 1).getValues()
  
  // Check for existing lookup values and add them to the classification column
  var lookupIndex = getColumnIndex(sheetName, lookupName)
  var lookupRange = dataSheet.getRange(1, lookupIndex, numRows, 1).getValues()
  
  for (var row in lookupRange) {
    var lookupValue = lookupRange[row].toString()
    for (var i in partialMatch) {
      if (lookupValue.indexOf(partialMatch[i].toString()) !== -1 && partialMatch[i].toString() !== '') {     
        var lookupRow = parseInt(i,10) + 1
        var outputValue = lookupSheet.getRange(lookupRow, 2).getValue()
        dataSheet.getRange(parseInt(row,10) + 1, classificationIndex).setValue(outputValue)
      }
    } 
  }
}

/**
* Gets the index for the column thats being used
*
* @param {sheetName}          : The name of the sheet find data
* @param {columnName}         : The name of the column
*
* @return The index number of the column
*/
function getColumnIndex(sheetName, columnName) {
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn()
  var columnHeaders = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues()[0]  
  var columnIndex = columnHeaders.indexOf(columnName) + 1
  return columnIndex
}
```

If I want to use this at work, I'll be dealing with multiple lookup columns across multiple tabs of data. So, my question is, is there a way to make this work faster?

Comment: Have you read best practices(See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details) and similar questions?

Comment: No, first time I've seen those. I'll go over them. Any suggestion on where to start?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

#### Modification points:

- I think that the mainly reason of your issue is that `getValue` and `setValue` are used in the loop. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) I think that when this situation is resolved, the cost will be able to be reduced.
- In order to reduce the cost of your script, I would like to propose the following flow.

  1. Retrieve the values using `getValues`.
  2. Create an array for putting to the Spreadsheet in the loop.

     - In this case, `getValue` and `setValue` are not used in the loop.
  3. Put the created array to the Spreadsheet. In this case, `setValues` is not used.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

From:

```
for (var row in lookupRange) {
  var lookupValue = lookupRange[row].toString()
  for (var i in partialMatch) {
    if (lookupValue.indexOf(partialMatch[i].toString()) !== -1 && partialMatch[i].toString() !== '') {     
      var lookupRow = parseInt(i,10) + 1
      var outputValue = lookupSheet.getRange(lookupRow, 2).getValue()
      dataSheet.getRange(parseInt(row,10) + 1, classificationIndex).setValue(outputValue)
    }
  } 
}
```

To:

```
// 1. Retrieve the values using `getValues`.
var temp = lookupSheet.getRange(1, 2, partialMatch.length, 1).getValues();

// 2. Create an array for putting to the Spreadsheet in the loop.
var obj = partialMatch.reduce((o, [e], i) => Object.assign(o, {[e]: i}), {});
var outputValue = lookupRange.map(([e]) => [e in obj ? temp[obj[e]] : ""]);

// 3. Put the created array to the Spreadsheet.
dataSheet.getRange(1, classificationIndex, outputValue.length).setValues(outputValue);
```

#### Note:

- Please use this script with enabling V8.
- If above modified script didn't work for your situation, when you provide the sample Spreadsheet and sample values of `vlookupName, sheetName, lookupName, classificationName`, I think that it will be useful for checking the issue.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)